# C#: Memory usage of an object

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management

Is there a way to find how much memory is used for a particular object? For example a List. Taking everything into account, like string interning and whatever is done by compiler/runtime environment/whatever.

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426396/how-much-memory-does-a-c-net-object-use

Comment: So it seems... sorry 'bout that :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much memory does a C#/.NET object use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426396/how-much-memory-does-a-c-net-object-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd really have to define *exactly* what you meant by "how much memory is used for a particular object". For instance, you could mean "if this object were garbage collected, how much would be freed" - or you could mean "how much memory does this object and everything it touches take up."

Your point about string interning is a good example. Suppose you do:

```
List<string> internedStrings = new List<string>();
List<string> nonInternedStrings = new List<string>();
for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    string tmp = new string(' ', i+1);
    nonInternedStrings.Add(tmp);
    tmp = tmp.Intern();
    internedStrings.Add(tmp);
}
```

Does `nonInternedStrings` really take up more memory than `internedStrings`? If `internedStrings` were garbage collected, it wouldn't free as much memory - but if `internedStrings` had never been *created* (including not interning each of its elements) then more memory would never have been required.

If you can be more specific about *exactly* what you mean, we may be able to help you. It's a complex issue though.

Comment: well, that is kind of exactly what I wanted to find out :p If, when I fetch a whole bunch of rows from the database (where many rows include the same strings in some columns), should I work on making sure they are interned, or shouldn't I bother with it?

Comment: I would do the simplest thing that works to start with, and then profile your app to see how much memory it uses. I wouldn't use String.Intern though - I've left an answer on your other question to explain why.

Answer (score 5):

[ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm) profiles the memory consumption of .NET code. I've had great results with it in the past.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a sibling of this [Delphi question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482604/recursive-class-instance-size-in-delphi/482643#482643). A naive algorithm won't take into account the difference between aggregation and composition. Even an algorithm based on mark and sweep won't tell you whether a hash table had to grow its internal array because an object was referenced by it. You probably are better off profiling your application for a variety of scenarios and plotting the resource usage against N, where N is some measure of the scale of your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried CLR Profiler 2.0?

Comment: No. Should maybe try that one out. Was hoping for something in code though. So I could sort of Console.WriteLine(MemoryUsageOf(someObject)) or something :p

Comment: CLR Profiler provides you with a wealth of information along memory information... The best way to write code is to write no code at all ;)

Comment: If it would work... Running the program works, launching my program works. But when I exit my program, the CLR Profiler throws an exception: