# What is the .NET equivalent of PHP's memory_get_usage?

Tags: asp.net

PHP has the function `memory_get_usage` to report the amount of memory a PHP script has. How can you do the same thing in .NET (ASP.NET C#)?

Also, can you report on how much memory an object is taking (e.g. SiteMap or DataTable)?

Answer (score 2):

For your current process you can use

```
Process currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
long totalBytesOfMemoryUsed = currentProcess.WorkingSet64;
long privateMemory = currentProcess.PrivateMemorySize64;
```

and

```
long managedMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
```

which will report the amount of managed memory allocated.

Getting the size for value types can be done with

```
var size = sizeof(int);
```

For an arbitrary object it's a bit more tricky since it can consist of many smaller objects of unknow size.

Also see

- SO - [Find out the size of a .net object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324053/find-out-the-size-of-a-net-object),
- SO - [Getting the size of a field in bytes with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c)
- SO - [C#: Memory usage of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555929/c-memory-usage-of-an-object/556061#556061)