# How to get all object (and its nested objects and links to objects) current RAM occupation?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

How to get all object (and its nested objects and links to objects) current RAM (Heap) occupation in .Net 2?

Comment: why silent downvote? it's a valid question for e.g. manual memory profiling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Memory usage of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555929/c-memory-usage-of-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about objects etc. But as as start you might want to check out the [`PerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) class. using this you can check the memory consumption of your application (testing your processes real memory consumption) by querying a performance counter (using System.Diagnostics)

```
string procName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
using (PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Private Bytes", procName))
    Console.WriteLine(pc.NextValue());
```

This class is fairly large and might contain something you can use...

I hope this helps.

*Note: Reading performance counter requires administrator privileges.*

Comment: I wonder about objects not whole process (objects that I created in my  process)

Comment: I don't know the entire class in great detail. But check out the link. there maybe something there that can help you...