# Byte size of object including size of members

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, sizeof

I want to know (for debugging and logging) the size of an object in bytes, but not like

```
Sizeof (Object)
```

but like a 'deep sizeof'. For example if the object contains a hash map or a list, the real size needed by that hash map or list should be added to the result. Is there any way to do this without having to add a

```
property Size : LongWord read GetByteSize;
```

to each and every little object?

Probably a stupid question, but I'll give it a try ;)

**EDIT**: Just found almost the same question:

[Recursive Class Instance Size in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482604/recursive-class-instance-size-in-delphi)

I guess, the question can be closed. Sorry about that!

Comment: Wouldn't be a good idea to add Delphi in the question name?

Comment: That's what tags are for...I consider it kind of redundant to add the programming language both as a tag and to include it in the title of EVERY question. Probably a matter of taste.

Comment: Great question! Everybody uses TObject but nobody has a clue about how much memory it actually takes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to write the code for this yourself.

Not sure of this works, but you can become very dirty:

- Find the object size in bytes. Using TObject.InstanceSize.
- Cast each group of 4 bytes to a pointer and then check if it is a TObject. You should be able to do that. If it is a TObject, you should repeat the step.

Comment: I was afraid of that...I have to make changes all over the place which I wanted to avoid...DAMN *g*...thanks anyway!

Comment: Added a possible solution, but it is very dirty and i'm not sure if you can do that.

Comment: Um, it's harder than that. You have to consider circular references, interfaces, and data which looks like an object but in fact is not. I think you'll find this difficult/impossible to perform successfully.

Comment: sorry, missed your comment, Craig. Sounds like its not worth the effort considering all potential problems. Maybe I'll give it a try anyway...

Comment: How are you going to distinguish between a 32 bit integer and a 32 bit TObject pointer? An array of primes won't contain any integer that you'll mistake for a pointer, but anything else might. Or you might get a raw pointer to some byte buffer.

Comment: What about RTTI? Can't that be helpful?

Comment: ahrg...forget about my comment...the size of all published members isn't helpful at all...would work in java I guess but not in Delphi. what a shame

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for debugging, have you looked at the FastMM4 memory allocator?  It's got some nice stuff for tracing memory leaks.

Comment: I'm not looking for memory leaks but for the size of certain internal data structures since the size varies with the input data.